# oneliner scramble program

Tags: python, code-golf, shuffle

It's that time of year again that programmers want to shuffle a list such that no element resides on its original position (at least in the Netherlands, we celebrate *Sinterklaas* and pick straws for deciding who writes who a poem). Does anyone have a nice Python **single statement** for that?

So, input example: `range(10)`

Output example: `[2,8,4,1,3,7,5,9,6,0]`

Wrong output would be `[2,8,4,1,3,5,7,9,6,0]` because the `5` is at its original position. This would mean that person 5 must write a poem to himself and that is less fun.

**edit** Many people repeat the assignment just as long as needed to *get lucky* and find that in fact the solution is satisfactory. This is a bad approach as in theory this can take infinitely long. The better approach is indeed suggested by Bart, but I can't get that into a oneliner for one reason or another...

**edit** By oneliner, I mean *single statement*. As it appears, Python is also able to compress multiple statements on a single line. I didn't know that. There are currently very nice solutions only using the semicolon to mimic multiline behaviour on a single line. Hence: "can you do it in a single statement?"

Comment: Why oneliner? Why not 5 or 6 lines?

Comment: Because I can do that myself. Dead easy. A oneliner is just a nice hobby for the cold and dark winterdays. :)

Comment: Single statment version of my answer:  
`exec "for i in range(1,len(L)):import random;r=random.randint(0,i-1);L[i],L[r]=L[r],L[i]"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found shuffle can be abused into solving this

```
from random import shuffle
L = ["Anne", "Beth", "Cath", "Dave", "Emma"]
shuffle(L, int=lambda n: int(n - 1))
print L
```

The distribution is not uniform however this was not a requirement.

```
#For 100,000 samples

(('Beth', 'Cath', 'Dave', 'Emma', 'Anne'), 13417)
(('Beth', 'Cath', 'Emma', 'Anne', 'Dave'), 6572)
(('Beth', 'Dave', 'Anne', 'Emma', 'Cath'), 3417)
(('Beth', 'Dave', 'Emma', 'Cath', 'Anne'), 6581)
(('Beth', 'Emma', 'Anne', 'Cath', 'Dave'), 3364)
(('Beth', 'Emma', 'Dave', 'Anne', 'Cath'), 6635)
(('Cath', 'Anne', 'Dave', 'Emma', 'Beth'), 1703)
(('Cath', 'Anne', 'Emma', 'Beth', 'Dave'), 1705)
(('Cath', 'Dave', 'Beth', 'Emma', 'Anne'), 6583)
(('Cath', 'Dave', 'Emma', 'Anne', 'Beth'), 3286)
(('Cath', 'Emma', 'Beth', 'Anne', 'Dave'), 3325)
(('Cath', 'Emma', 'Dave', 'Beth', 'Anne'), 3421)
(('Dave', 'Anne', 'Beth', 'Emma', 'Cath'), 1653)
(('Dave', 'Anne', 'Emma', 'Cath', 'Beth'), 1664)
(('Dave', 'Cath', 'Anne', 'Emma', 'Beth'), 3349)
(('Dave', 'Cath', 'Emma', 'Beth', 'Anne'), 6727)
(('Dave', 'Emma', 'Anne', 'Beth', 'Cath'), 3319)
(('Dave', 'Emma', 'Beth', 'Cath', 'Anne'), 3323)
(('Emma', 'Anne', 'Beth', 'Cath', 'Dave'), 1682)
(('Emma', 'Anne', 'Dave', 'Beth', 'Cath'), 1656)
(('Emma', 'Cath', 'Anne', 'Beth', 'Dave'), 3276)
(('Emma', 'Cath', 'Dave', 'Anne', 'Beth'), 6638)
(('Emma', 'Dave', 'Anne', 'Cath', 'Beth'), 3358)
(('Emma', 'Dave', 'Beth', 'Anne', 'Cath'), 3346)
```

For a uniform distribution, this (longer) version can be used

```
from random import shuffle,randint
L=["Anne", "Beth", "Cath", "Dave", "Emma"]
shuffle(L, random=lambda: 1, int=lambda n: randint(0, n - 2))
print L

# For 100,000 samples

(('Beth', 'Cath', 'Dave', 'Emma', 'Anne'), 4157)
(('Beth', 'Cath', 'Emma', 'Anne', 'Dave'), 4155)
(('Beth', 'Dave', 'Anne', 'Emma', 'Cath'), 4099)
(('Beth', 'Dave', 'Emma', 'Cath', 'Anne'), 4141)
(('Beth', 'Emma', 'Anne', 'Cath', 'Dave'), 4243)
(('Beth', 'Emma', 'Dave', 'Anne', 'Cath'), 4208)
(('Cath', 'Anne', 'Dave', 'Emma', 'Beth'), 4219)
(('Cath', 'Anne', 'Emma', 'Beth', 'Dave'), 4087)
(('Cath', 'Dave', 'Beth', 'Emma', 'Anne'), 4117)
(('Cath', 'Dave', 'Emma', 'Anne', 'Beth'), 4127)
(('Cath', 'Emma', 'Beth', 'Anne', 'Dave'), 4198)
(('Cath', 'Emma', 'Dave', 'Beth', 'Anne'), 4210)
(('Dave', 'Anne', 'Beth', 'Emma', 'Cath'), 4179)
(('Dave', 'Anne', 'Emma', 'Cath', 'Beth'), 4119)
(('Dave', 'Cath', 'Anne', 'Emma', 'Beth'), 4143)
(('Dave', 'Cath', 'Emma', 'Beth', 'Anne'), 4203)
(('Dave', 'Emma', 'Anne', 'Beth', 'Cath'), 4252)
(('Dave', 'Emma', 'Beth', 'Cath', 'Anne'), 4159)
(('Emma', 'Anne', 'Beth', 'Cath', 'Dave'), 4193)
(('Emma', 'Anne', 'Dave', 'Beth', 'Cath'), 4177)
(('Emma', 'Cath', 'Anne', 'Beth', 'Dave'), 4087)
(('Emma', 'Cath', 'Dave', 'Anne', 'Beth'), 4150)
(('Emma', 'Dave', 'Anne', 'Cath', 'Beth'), 4268)
(('Emma', 'Dave', 'Beth', 'Anne', 'Cath'), 4109)
```

**How it works**

Here is the code for `random.shuffle()`

```
def shuffle(self, x, random=None, int=int):
    """x, random=random.random -> shuffle list x in place; return None.

    Optional arg random is a 0-argument function returning a random
    float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, the standard random.random.
    """

    if random is None:
        random = self.random
    for i in reversed(xrange(1, len(x))):
        # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = int(random() * (i+1))
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

Both solutions work by targeting the line `j = int(random() * (i+1))`

The first(non uniform) effectively makes the line work like this

```
j = int(random() * (i + 1) - 1)
```

So instead of a range of (1..i) we obtain (0..i-1)

The second solution replaces `random()` with a function that always returns 1, and uses `randint` instead of `int`. So the line now works like this

```
j = randint(0, i - 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

After shuffling the list of numbers, let the `[i]`th person write a poem (and buy a present!) for the `[i+1]`th person in the list: that way, there can never be someone who draws him- or herself. Of course, the last one should point to the first...

Comment: That is exactly my multiline implementation!! Because this is guaranteed to end in linear time in contrast with other methods mentioned here. But shuffling and shifting is very difficult in a oneliner. Can you give code?

Comment: That only generates "full circles", something like persons one and two writing each other poems will not be covered...

Comment: @sth attentive! looks like the same holds for Glex's Ruby code?

Answer (score 3):

Shifting every element in the list by one in a circular manner, [as suggested by Bart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735561/oneliner-scramble-program/1735584#1735584), is easy:

```
>>> def shift(seq):
...     return seq[-1:] + seq[:-1]
... 
>>> shift(range(10))
[9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

**As for a random solution**: in this case the request for a one-liner is not such a good idea, since the obvious function to use, namely [`random.shuffle`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/random.html#random.shuffle), performs its task in place. In other words: it has a *side effect*, something one usually tries to avoid in list comprehensions. There is a way around this though, as [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170701/paul) points out, namely by using [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/random.html#random.sample). The following code shows two one-liners which use these functions (note the use of `not shuffle`, to work around the fact that `shuffle` returns `None`...):

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> def shake_it(seq):
...     return next(c for c in repeat(seq[::]) if not shuffle(c) and all(a != b for a, b in zip(seq, c)))
... 
>>> shake_it(range(10))
[7, 9, 0, 2, 6, 8, 5, 1, 4, 3]
>>> 
>>> from itertools import count
>>> from random import sample
>>> def shake_it(seq):
...     return next(c for c in (sample(seq, len(seq)) for _ in count()) if all(a != b for a, b in zip(seq, c)))
... 
>>> shake_it(range(10))
[1, 3, 9, 5, 2, 6, 8, 4, 0, 7]
```

Myself, I'd go with this one:

```
>>> def shake_it(seq):
...     res = seq[::]
...     while any(a == b for a, b in zip(res, seq)):
...         shuffle(res)
...     return res
... 
>>> shake_it(range(10))
[5, 7, 9, 2, 6, 8, 3, 0, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Substitute `random.shuffle(x)` for `random.sample(x, len(x))` to get a returned value if you like.

Comment: @Paul: good point! I've updated the answer with a one-liner which uses `shuffle`.

Comment: I think this oneliner way of thinking is very similar to Wim's, whre his is _far_ more easy to read. The use of `repeat` though is very promising. I didn't know that function and I bet it's going to be part of the final solution.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, Wim's solutions rely on the assumption that the input is `range(n)` (that is, a list of successive numbers, starting at zero). My code makes no such assumptions, and is thus more general. (I.e., I can shuffle a list of actual Dutch names ;)

Answer (score 1):

My first Python program in a long while.  Unlike many of the above programs, this one takes O(n) time.

```
s = set(range(10))
r = list()
for i in range(10):
    s2 = s - set([i])
    val = s2.pop()
    r.append(val)
    s.discard(val)

print r
```

*UPDATE*: Paul showed that the above program was incorrect.  Thanks, Paul.  Here's a different, better version of the same program:

```
s = range(10)
for i in range(9):
    r = random.randrange(i+1, 10)
    s[i], s[r] = s[r], s[i]

print s
```

Comment: do you mean something like this: `reduce(lambda a,i:a+[random.choice(list(set(x)-set(a+[i])))], x, [])`? It throws an IndexError when the last remaining item is forced to reference itself.

Comment: Paul -- if it throws an IndexError, then it's not a good re-writing of my code.

Comment: Ok, I just don't understand your code. Now I run your code and it **always** gives the same outcome. For range(10), r is always `[1, 0, 3, 2, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. So not really random.

Comment: Yeah; `pop()` returns an arbitrary, rather than a random, element from a list.  Would my answer be easier to understand if I used lists instead of sets?

Comment: Let's assume there was in fact a `.poprandom()` on sets, then your algorithm would throw IndexError when the last remaining item in s was the last element in the list (`9` in the example of range(10)).

Comment: Aha -- I see the problem.  You're absolutely right: one time in ten, a .poprandom() solution would fail.  Excellent catch!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it with O(n) time and O(1) extra memory:

Comprehensible code:

```
def shuffle(a)
  n = a.length
  (0..n - 2).each do |i|
    r = rand(n - i - 1) + i + 1
    a[r], a[i] = a[i], a[r]
  end
  a
end
```

A one-liner (assumes "a" is the array):

```
n = a.length and (0..n - 2).each {|i| r = rand(n - i - 1) + i + 1; a[r], a[i] = a[i], a[r]}
```

The code is in ruby, but without any doubt it's easily translatable to python

Cheers

P.S.: The solution modifies the array.

Answer (score 1):

"One-liner" in fixed O(n) time:

```
import random; a=range(10)  # setup (could read in names instead)
for i in range(len(a)-1,0,-1): j=random.randint(0,i-1); a[j],a[i]=a[i],a[j]
print a  # output
```

The loop picks elements from the maximum index (len(a)-1) down to the next-smallest (1).  The choice pool for element k only includes indices from 0 to k-1; once picked, an element will not be moved again.

After the scramble, no element can reside in its original position, because:

- if element j is picked for some slot i>j, it will stay there
- otherwise, element j will be swapped with some other element from slot i<j, which will stay there
- except for the element in slot 0, which will be swapped unconditionally with the element in slot 1 (in the final iteration of the loop) if it has not already been displaced.

[edit: this is logically equivalent to the Ruby answer, I think]

Comment: Great! And yes it is like the ruby solution and I like the algo for it's simplicity. Can you write it in one statement?

Comment: Well, you could ";eval'...'" the middle line, but that would just be sad.

Answer (score 1):

This one is O(N). Having the import in the loops is a bit silly, but you wanted a one liner

```
L=range(10)
for i in range(1,len(L)):import random;r=random.randint(0,i-1);L[i],L[r]=L[r],L[i]
print L
```

Here is the output distribution when L=range(5) for 100000 samples

```
((1, 2, 3, 4, 0), 4231)
((1, 2, 4, 0, 3), 4115)
((1, 3, 0, 4, 2), 4151)
((1, 3, 4, 2, 0), 4108)
((1, 4, 0, 2, 3), 4254)
((1, 4, 3, 0, 2), 4101)
((2, 0, 3, 4, 1), 4158)
((2, 0, 4, 1, 3), 4177)
((2, 3, 1, 4, 0), 4190)
((2, 3, 4, 0, 1), 4117)
((2, 4, 1, 0, 3), 4194)
((2, 4, 3, 1, 0), 4205)
((3, 0, 1, 4, 2), 4325)
((3, 0, 4, 2, 1), 4109)
((3, 2, 0, 4, 1), 4131)
((3, 2, 4, 1, 0), 4153)
((3, 4, 0, 1, 2), 4081)
((3, 4, 1, 2, 0), 4118)
((4, 0, 1, 2, 3), 4294)
((4, 0, 3, 1, 2), 4167)
((4, 2, 0, 1, 3), 4220)
((4, 2, 3, 0, 1), 4179)
((4, 3, 0, 2, 1), 4090)
((4, 3, 1, 0, 2), 4132)
```

Comment: Of course, take import out of the line. Furthermore, I will edit my question as I find myself searching for _a single statement_ rather than a "oneliner that actually comprises multiple statements".

Comment: I posted another answer, but I've left this one here too as I think this is a good multiple statement solution

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't a one-liner, but this works

```
import random
def sinterklaas(n):
    l=[]
    for a in range(n):
        l.append(-1)

    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        index = random.randint(0,n-1)
        if l[index] == -1 and index != i:
        l[index] = i
            i += 1
```

Cheers

Comment: This: `l=[]; for a in range(n): l.append(-1)` is really this: `l = [-1] * n`.

Comment: Thank you for this awesome piece of information. I had not known this before.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random; u = range(10)
while sum(u[i]==i for i in range(10)): random.shuffle(u)
```

(Ok, I have a line 0 in there too...)

Comment: I think you meant import random, not range!

Comment: Duh, that's 5 edits needed to get a oneliner working... Must...get...coffee...!!

Comment: good work! though it is taking overly much computation (and is _theoretically_ not guaranteed to finish)

Comment: Oh, it's theoretically guaranteed to finish.  It's not guaranteed to finish within any particular *time*, but I think the expected number of iterations is asymptotically constant.

Comment: No it's not guaranteed to finish. If your random number generator can only generate permutations that don't match the *don't write poem to self* rule, you can try for a *very* long time... (I know, it'd be a pretty pathetic random generator, but we're talking theoretical, right?)

Answer (score 0):

For one in O(n):

```
u=range(10); random.shuffle(u); v=[ u[u[i]] for i in range(10) ]; return [ v[(u[i]+1)%10] for i in u ]
```

`u` is the inverse of function `v`, so `v[u[i]+1]` is effectively the element following i in array `v`.

Comment: I think this is going in a good direction. Can you also do it without the semicolons? You can also shuffle as a returned value like this if you like: `shuffled = random.sample(x, len(x))`

Comment: I tried running your program.  My return was: [0, 1, 5, 2, 6, 9, 3, 4, 7, 8].  I feel sorry for the first and second people!

Answer (score 0):

Here's Stephan202's circular shift implemented as a one-liner with a randomly-chosen shift increment:

```
from random import randrange; s = range(10); r = randrange(1,len(s)-1); print s[-r:] + s[:-r]
```

Comment: Yes, but it is not shuffling.