# Are there any ways to scramble strings in python?

Tags: python, string, list, scramble

I'm writing a program and I need to scramble the letters of `string`s from a `list` in python. For instance I have a `list` of `string`s like:

```
l = ['foo', 'biology', 'sequence']
```

And I want something like this:

```
l = ['ofo', 'lbyoogil', 'qceeenus']
```

What is the best way to do it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735561/oneliner-scramble-program

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Python has batteries included..

```
>>> from random import shuffle

>>> def shuffle_word(word):
...    word = list(word)
...    shuffle(word)
...    return ''.join(word)
```

A list comprehension is an easy way to create a new list:

```
>>> L = ['foo', 'biology', 'sequence']
>>> [shuffle_word(word) for word in L]
['ofo', 'lbyooil', 'qceaenes']
```

Comment: +1 batteries included! careful they aren't the regular 9v ones either.

Comment: A list comprehension may not always be the best approach, generator expressions or mappings may be better. I this instance, I would go for `map()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
import random

words = ['foo', 'biology', 'sequence']
words = [''.join(random.sample(word, len(word))) for word in words]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use random.shuffle:

```
>>> import random
>>> x = "sequence"
>>> l = list(x)
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> y = ''.join(l)
>>> y
'quncesee'
>>>
```

From this you can build up a function to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Like those before me, I'd use [`random.shuffle()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
>>> import random
>>> def mixup(word):
...     as_list_of_letters = list(word)
...     random.shuffle(as_list_of_letters)
...     return ''.join(as_list_of_letters)
...
>>> map(mixup, l)
['oof', 'iogylob', 'seucqene']
>>> map(mixup, l)
['foo', 'byolgio', 'ueseqcen']
>>> map(mixup, l)
['oof', 'yobgloi', 'enescque']
>>> map(mixup, l)
['oof', 'yolbgoi', 'qsecnuee']
```

See also:

- [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of styling added, but it does the job!

```py
import random
import os
from colorama import Style, Fore
import colorama
from click import pause
import time

colorama.init()

def main(word):

    x = word
    l = list(x)
    random.shuffle(l)
    y = ''.join(l)

    print(Fore.YELLOW + '  [>] Output: ' + y + Style.RESET_ALL)

    #time.sleep(1)

    pause(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT + '\n  [!] Press any key to exit...' + Style.RESET_ALL)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.system('cls')
    print(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT + '======= Input Scrambler =======\n' + Style.RESET_ALL)
    word = input(Fore.CYAN + '  [>] Input: ')
    print(Style.RESET_ALL)
    main(word)
```