# Shuffle string without shuffling the first and last char

Tags: python

I've tried:

```
text="Sample sentence."
random.shuffle(text)
print(''.join(text))
```

But this shuffles everything, possible output:

```
nmactnpleSSe ee
```

I want something like this:

```
Smplea ntesence.
```

Comment: You can't shuffle a string - they are immutable. So the output shown does not correspond to the code that you have posted.

Comment: `text[0] + ''.join(random.shuffle(list(text[1:-1]))) + text[-1]` as long as `len(text)` larger than 1. The idea is to maintain first and last and shuffle in between

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scramble the words in a sentence - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161075/how-to-scramble-the-words-in-a-sentence-python)

Comment: @YossiLevi Your `shuffle` returns something other than `None`?

Comment: correct. this one is absolutely better - `c = list(text[1:-1]);random.shuffle(c);print(text[1] + ''.join(c) + text[-1])`. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just extract and shuffle the bit you want, and then reassemble it afterwards.

```
import random

text = "Sample sentence."

text1 = list(text[1:-1])
random.shuffle(text1)

text2 = text[0] + ''.join(text1) + text[-1]

print(text2)
```

*Note: this answers the question as stated regarding shuffling all except the first and last character. The example shown in the question appears to be a special case, where each word gets shuffled separately. This is a possible outcome, but not a guaranteed one.*

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
import random

text = 'Sample sentence.'
lst = [char for char in text[1:-1]]  
random.shuffle(lst)
lst.append(text[-1])
lst.insert(0,text[0])
print(''.join(lst))
```