# im created a word scrambler and i am having difficulty implementing a block of code that scrambles each word individually

Tags: python-3.x

```
print (' ')
print ('=================================')
print ('Options:')
print ('A.) Hello world ---> olHle dlWro')
print ('B.) Hello world ---> Hlelo Wlord')

while True:
#changes input to lowercase letters
  sctype = input('Enter scramble type')
  sclower = sctype.lower()

#if 'a' or 'b' not in sctype:
#print ('follow directions')

#input and input related variables
  print ('There is a 26 character limit')
  text = input(' Type your message or word: ')
  length = len(text)
  remaining = 26 - length
  counter = 1
```

just a fancy cage for length and remaining

```
  print ('============================')
  print ('||Length:', length, 'Remaining:', remaining, '||')
  print ('============================')
```

letter order and loop for option A
dash replaces spaces in original text with dashes 
a fills in extra character space with spaces so length = 26
b scrambles a in the order it is given

```
  if sclower == 'a':
    print ('Results for option  A')
    print (' ')
    dash = text.replace(" ", "-")
    a = dash + ' ' * remaining
    b = a[25] + a[0] + a[24] + a[1] + a[23] + a[2] + a[22] + a[3] + a[21] + 
a[4] + a[20] + a[5] + a[19] + a[6] + a[18] + a[7] + a[17] + a[8] + a[16] + 
a[9] + a[15] + a[10] + a[14] + a[11] + a[13] + a[12]
    a = b
```

scrambles a the amount its original text length is

```
    if a == b:
      while counter <= length:
        b = a[25] + a[0] + a[24] + a[1] + a[23] + a[2] + a[22] + a[3] + 
a[21] + a[4] + a[20] + a[5] + a[19] + a[6] + a[18] + a[7] + a[17] + a[8] + 
a[16] + a[9] + a[15] + a[10] + a[14] + a[11] + a[13] + a[12]
        a = b 
        nospaces = b.replace(" ", "") #deletes all spaces made in var a
        nodashes = nospaces.replace("-", " ") #changes all dashes to spaces
        print (counter, '.)', nodashes)
        counter += 1 
        print (' ')
```

option b

```
  elif sclower == 'b':
  print ('Results for option  B')
  print (' ')
  dash = text.replace(" ", "-")
  a = dash + ' ' * remaining
  b = a[21] + a[23] + a[20] + a[25] + a[22] + a[24] + a[19] + a[2] + a[18] + 
a[0] + a[16] + a[1] + a[17] + a[4] + a[15] + a[3] + a[14] + a[5] + a[13] + 
a[7] + a[11] + a[6] + a[10] + a[9] + a[12] + a[18]
  a = b

  if a == b:
    while counter <= length :
      b = a[21] + a[23] + a[20] + a[25] + a[22] + a[24] + a[19] + a[2] + 
a[18] + a[0] + a[16] + a[1] + a[17] + a[4] + a[15] + a[3] + a[14] + a[5] + 
a[13] + a[7] + a[11] + a[6] + a[10] + a[9] + a[12] + a[18]
      a = b 
      nospaces = b.replace(" ", "")
      nodashes = nospaces.replace("-", " ")
      print (counter, '.)', nodashes)
      counter += 1 
      print (' ')

  if input("Repeat the program? (Y/N)").strip().upper() != 'Y':
    break
```

i need to impliment the code below into the code above. this will allow the program to scramble each word within a string individually instead of all at once

```
counter = 0
text = 'Hello World'
split = str.split(text)

for str in split:
  no_name = split[counter]
  scramble = c[4] + c[0] + c[3] + c[1] + c[2]
  counter += 1
  print (scramble, end=" ")
```

PLEASE NOTE: the variable "text" should allow user input in the final version, above is just an example of the structure

Comment: do you have to manually scramble the input with those long character indices? seems like you could simplify things a lot using `from random import shuffle` like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181304/are-there-any-way-to-scramble-strings-in-python

Comment: and why are you only scrambling 5 characters in the code at the bottom? can't each word in the message be any length up to 26 characters total?

Comment: @downshift you do not have to manually scramble the input. if im understanding your question correctly, variable b is the order in which the input (a) will be arranged. Also, the code at the bottom only arranges 5 letters because it serves only as an example of what should be added to the top. to save some time i only included 5.